# Using PETSc on makefile within my user-defined makefile

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, include-path, petsc

I am new in `PETSc`. I have a big c++ code and I want to add `PETSc` to some of the files that I already have, so I have to change my makefile in a way that it can compile PETSc as well.

Is it possible to have two different makefiles and then call `PETSc` makefile within my own makefile? if so, how can I do this?

Does anyone have any experience in linking `PETSc` to their own code?

By the way, I am using Linux as my operating system.

Comment: You want your build to build PETSc as well as building your code or you want your code to use an already built PETSc?

Comment: Yes I want my build to build PETSc as well as building my code

Comment: It is possible, but it's a bit complicated. PETSc's makefile system is hard to understand.

Comment: At the simplest you could always just have the PETSc source in a directory in your tree and `make -C <PETSCdir>` as a prereq for your targets. That's not going to track prerequisites well at all but it would work. (A fancier setup would be to create targets for the various tools/libraries that PETSc builds that you depend on and use `make -C <PETScdir> <target>` for whatever builds that tool/library.)

Comment: So you mean I dont have to add PETSc commands in my own makefile and just first compile PETSc and then complie my own C++ code? I did what you said but it is not working and it shows me error.

Comment: I just added { #include "tport_SolveLS.hpp" }in one of my codes. Then I compiled PETSc by using {make -C /opt/petsc-3.4.2/src/ksp} and then I compiled my own code by using {make clean ; make all} but the error showed that my code did not understand PETSc library and it shows : error: petscksp.h: No such file or directory
I would be grateful if anyone help me with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**edit:** Though this is an old post, I am sure there are still people struggling with this.

Furthermore, things apparently changed slightly for petsc 3.6.x (and slepc 3.6.x).

I currently use the following lines in my ubuntu 14.04 LTS makefile for F90 files (using both petsc 3.6.1 and slepc 3.6.0):

```
# PETSC and SLEPC directories
PETSC_DIR = /opt/petsc-3.6.1
SLEPC_DIR = /opt/slepc-3.6.0
include  $(PETSC_DIR)/lib/petsc/conf/variables
include  $(SLEPC_DIR)/lib/slepc/conf/slepc_variables
```

Using this I can construct the

```
# Compiler command
COMPILE = $(COMP_DIR) $(COMP_FLAGS) $(PETSC_FC_INCLUDES) $(SLEPC_INCLUDE)
```

where `COMP_DIR` has to be set manually (e.g. `COMP_DIR = /usr/bin/mpif90` or `COMP_DIR = /usr/bin/gfortran`) and `COMP_FLAGS` are additional flags (e.g. '-g O0'), as well as the

```
# Link command
LINK = $(LINK_DIR) &(LINK_FLAGS)
```

where again `LINK_DIR` has to be set manually (e.g. `/usr/bin/g++`) and `LINK_FLAGS` contains additional flags (e.g. `-fPIC`).

These can then be used to create rules to compile the F90 files (I am sure C is pretty similar):

```
%.o : %.f90
$(COMPILE) -c $<
```

and the main program:

```
main:   $(ObjectFiles) main.o
$(LINK) -o $@ $(ObjectFiles) main.o $(LINK_LIB) $(PETSC_LIB) $(SLEPC_LIB)
```

where `ObjectFiles` contains a list of all the files in the project and `LINK_LIB` corresponds to other links (e.g. `-lgfortran`).

This works fine for me, yet suggestions for improvements are always welcome.

**original post:**
Instead of the hack described by Divakar, you can easily find out the link flags and the include directories for compilation by running

```
make getlinklibs
make getincludedirs
```

in the main petsc directory, as described [here](http://tacc-web.austin.utexas.edu/veijkhout/public_html/taccnotes/petsclinking/petsclinking.html)...

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. By the way I solved the problem that I have by using Netbeans instead of writing the makefile myself. I created a project in Netbeans and added the libraries that are needed from PETSc (which we can find by using getlinklibs).

Answer (score 3):

I am not too familiar with Makefiles, so I would just list out the “hack” method. We will look into the “hack” method in this text later on. I have a Makefile and a sample source code, ex1.cpp that uses few PETSc arrays, vectors, functions along with my own regular C/C++ array that does data exchange with PETSc array and vectors. This could be thought of as a miniature version of your case.

My Makefile –

```
PETSC_DIR=/usr/local/petsc

include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/rules
include ${PETSC_DIR}/conf/test

CLINKER=g++

ex1 : ex1.o chkopts
    ${CLINKER} -w -o ex1 ex1.o ${PETSC_LIB}
    ${RM} ex1.o 
    ./ex1
```

Of course you need to edit PETSC_DIR to the PETSc directory location on your system. Typing “make ex1” would compile and link the source code to create an executable and execute it.

After I do “make ex1” on my system, the two process outputs of compilation and linking are shown, that are listed here as follows:

Compilation -

> /usr/local/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/bin/mpicc -o ex1.o -c -fPIC -Wall
>   -Wwrite-strings -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unknown-pragmas -g3 -fno-inline -O0   -I/usr/local/petsc/include -I/usr/local/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/include  ex1.cpp

Linking -

> g++ -w -o ex1 ex1.o
>   -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib -L/usr/local/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib  -lpetsc -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib -lflapack -lfblas -lX11 -lpthread -lm -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath,/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmpichf90 -lgfortran -lm -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lm -lmpichcxx -lstdc++ -ldl -lmpich -lopa -lmpl -lrt -lpthread -lgcc_s –ldl

So the “hack” trick is that you run the Makefile and separate the compilation and linking process outputs with this PETSc case. You do the same with your original source code that is PETSc-free and note down compilation and linking process outputs with it.

Let’s suppose with PETSc-free version, the compilation process output  is **g++ -o ex1.o –I/random_path ex1.cpp** and linking process output is **g++ -w -o ex1 ex1.o –llib1 –L/random_lib2**.

Next step is to merge the compilation paths for PETSc code and PETSc-free code and same with linking.
Thus, the modified compilation and linking processes would be:

Modified Compilation -

> /usr/local/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/bin/mpicc -o ex1.o -c -fPIC -Wall
>   -Wwrite-strings -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-unknown-pragmas -g3 -fno-inline -O0   -I/usr/local/petsc/include -I/usr/local/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/include  **–I/random_path** ex1.cpp

Modified Linking –

> g++ -w -o ex1 ex1.o
>   -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib -L/usr/local/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib  -lpetsc -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/petsc/arch-linux2-c-debug/lib -lflapack -lfblas -lX11 -lpthread -lm -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath,/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lmpichf90 -lgfortran -lm -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lm -lmpichcxx -lstdc++ -ldl -lmpich -lopa -lmpl -lrt -lpthread -lgcc_s –ldl **–llib1 –L/random_lib2**

You may type the modified commands directly onto the terminal or make a BASH script to run them.

The PETSc example code that calculates reciprocal of the numbers in an array is listed below for the sake of reference:

```
// EX1.CPP
#include <petscvec.h>
#include <petscmat.h>
#include <petscksp.h>

Vec Arr2Vec(double *arr2, int SIZE);

// MAIN FUNCTION
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    // Initialize PetSc
    PetscInitialize(&argc,&argv,(char*)0,"Testing a program!");

    // Initialize parameters
    int SIZE = 3;
    PetscErrorCode ierr;

    // **** Create a regular arary and set it with random numbers
    double  * arr2;
    arr2 = new double [SIZE];

    arr2[0] = 0.1;
    arr2[1] = 0.4;
    arr2[2] = 0.2;

    // Convert regular arary to PETSc vector [Note that this must do the same effect as the two-step process of conversion from regular array to PETSc arary and that to PETSc vector as listed above]
    Vec x = Arr2Vec(arr2, SIZE);

    printf("Reciprocal Vector : \n"); VecReciprocal(x);
    VecView(x,PETSC_VIEWER_STDOUT_WORLD);

    //Cleanup
    ierr = VecDestroy(&x);
    CHKERRQ(ierr);
    PetscFinalize();

    return 0;
}

Vec Arr2Vec(double *arr2, int SIZE)
{
  PetscScalar *array1;
  PetscMalloc(SIZE*sizeof(PetscScalar),&array1);

  for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    array1[i]=arr2[i];

    // Setup vector
  Vec x;
  VecCreate(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&x);
  VecSetSizes(x,PETSC_DECIDE,SIZE);
  VecSetFromOptions(x);

  // Place PetSc array as Vector
  VecPlaceArray(x,array1);

  return x;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive explanation. I am going to apply the method you mentioned. Meanwhile I am using NetBeans as a tool to compile the PETSc files together with my own c++ code. Using NetBeans makes me able to avoid writing a makefile cause it produce a makefile itself. If you are interested in knowing how to compile with NetBeans I would be grateful to tell you how to do that.

Comment: I am sort of old-school and stay away from IDEs as much as possible. But I will get back to you if I try to use NetBeans. Appreciate your help too!

Comment: Also, I have few other custom codes to do data exchange between regular C/C++ arrays, PETSc arrays and PETSc vectors. Let me know if you need more examples on those.

Comment: @Mahnaz, If it has answered your question, you might think of marking the answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark next to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I really appreciate your answers. I would be grateful if you give me more examples on exchanging data between PETSc and C++.

Comment: After being able to compile PETSc and my C++ code together, I am trying to substitute the vectors from c++ code that I already have into PETSc vectors. Do you have any examples about this task?

Answer (score 1):

I have met with the same problem, and for that I made a simple but comprehensive `makefile` (to be used under Linux OS).
Suppose that the code is stored in `ex_1.cpp`. PETSc is assumed to be installed in `/usr/local/petsc/petsc-3.7.4`. One can find the proper environmental variables in `configure.log` file after installation of PETSc.

One can then use the following `makefile` to compile and link the C++ code:

```
# PETSC 3.7.4 Makefile (Linux)
#----------------------------------------

# NOTE: look up `configure.log` in PETSc folder to obtain
# the proper environmental parametres
PETSC_DIR=/usr/local/petsc/petsc-3.7.4
PETSC_ARCH=arch-linux2-c-debug
PETSC_CONFIGDIR=${PETSC_DIR}/lib/petsc/

include ${PETSC_CONFIGDIR}/conf/variables
include ${PETSC_CONFIGDIR}/conf/rules
include ${PETSC_CONFIGDIR}/conf/test

# compile and link options
LOCDIR= ./
DIRS =
CXX_STD = -std=c++11
CXX_CFLAGS = ${CXX_STD} ${CXX_FLAGS} ${PETSC_CCPPFLAGS} 
LIBS = ${PETSC_LIB}
CXX_LFLAGS = ${CXX_STD}

#OBJS = $(SRC1:.cpp=.o)
#----------------------------------------

.PHONY: default allclean run_1

default: chkopts
    @echo "--- PETSC CONFIGURATION -----------------"
    @if [ "${CUDAC}" != "" ]; then \
        echo "Using CUDA compile: ${PETSC_CUCOMPILE}";\
    fi
    @echo "Using C/C++ linker: ${PCC_LINKER}"
    @echo "Using C/C++ flags: ${PCC_LINKER_FLAGS}"
    @echo "Using C++ flags: ${CXX_FLAGS}"
    @echo "-----------------------------------------"
    @echo "Using libraries: ${PETSC_LIB}"
    @echo "-----------------------------------------"
    @echo "Using mpiexec: ${MPIEXEC}"
    @echo "========================================="

ex_1: default ex_1.o 
    @echo "---- LINK -----"
    ${CXX} -w -o ex_1.out ex_1.o ${LIBS} ${CXX_LFLAGS}
    -${RM} ex_1.o
    @echo "==============="

ex_1.o:
    @echo "--- COMPILE ---"
    ${CXX} -o ex_1.o -c ex_1.cpp ${CXX_CFLAGS}
    @echo "==============="

run_1:
    @echo "==============="
    @echo "--- EXECUTE ---"
    @echo "starting on `hostname` at `date`"
    @echo "machine characteristics: `uname -a`"
    @echo "==============="
    ${MPIEXEC} -n 1 ./ex_1.out #-info
    @echo "==============="

 allclean: clean
    -@${RM} *.out
```

Note that `chkopts` and `clean` rules are already defined by PETSc.
The executable file will be stored as `ex_1.out`. 
To compile and link the code, use `make ex_1` and to run the executable file, use `make run_1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, however I am sure there are still people struggling with this

I didn't tried in C/C++ but in Fortran, adding the correct folders and libraries, in the compiler/linker commands, worked for me:

```
-I${PETSC_DIR}/include
-L${PETSC_DIR}/lib -lpetscsys -lpetscXXX
```

without the need of including variables/rules/test file, that broke my makefile.

Hope it helps...